# error: cannot find symbol variable MyClass in android

Tags: java, android

I have a simple project. In this project I created a `java library` as follows:

```
package com.example;
import java.lang.Integer;
public class Sum {
public static Integer counter(int number_1, int number_2){
    return number_1 + number_2;
}
}
```

And in `MainActivit` class I have the following code:

```
package com.example.tec.myapplication;
import com.example.Sum;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textView;
    int number_1 = 100;
    int number_2 = 100;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Integer integer =  Sum.counter(number_1, number_2);
    textView.setText(integer.toString());
    }}
```

In appearance, My codes have no grammatical problem and I do not get even a warning from the android studio. But when I click on the `run` option I get the following errors:

```
C:\Users\tec\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\java\com\example\tec\myapplication\MainActivity.java

Error:(2, 19) error: cannot find symbol class MyClass
Error:(17, 24) error: cannot find symbol variable MyClass
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

In the above code, seems I have three errors.

Comment: show code where MyClass is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the`settings.gradle` file of your Android module you need to `include` a reference to your Java module. Something like:

`include ":utils", ":sum"`

More info about this topic here: http://rominirani.com/2014/07/29/gradle-tutorial-part-3-multiple-java-projects/